# With today's technology, is it possible to charge a battery over 100% without exploding?

Tags: batteries

We all know who Iron Man is.

Hollywood makes a nice job to make him look like a genious in electronic.

However, there is a scene where his suit charges it's batteries to 475%.

There is another question, on another website, adressing one part of this issue.
You can read it on [Can Iron Man recharge his suit from lightning?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/30886/can-iron-man-recharge-his-suit-from-lightning).

What I'm asking here is if it is possible to charge a battery (no sci-fi stuff, please), with current technoligy, to over 100% of it's charge without exploding?

Comment: By definition 100% is when the battery is full, so when you could cram more energy into it, it wasn't full yet, so when with that technology you charge the battery to whatever full it is then, it is at 100%

Comment: This battery goes to 11.

Comment: @PlasmaHH You can always force more water into a full glass. Sure, there will be a point that the water will spill. But until then, there is some surface tension keeping the water inside. Since enectricity flow is compared to water flow, one may assume the same will happen. I just want to know if it is possible to happen. With or without damage. (Without exploding, obviously).

Comment: @geometrikal What do you mean?

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel: I define the amount of water with surface tension as 100%. Now fill it to 101

Comment: It all comes down to where 100% is defined. Designers usually add margin and the advertised level is "100%" could you get 105% probably, but 475% well thats hollywood

Comment: @JonRB I know that 475% is just Hollywood. That's why I'm just asking above 100%.

Comment: @PlasmaHH That is possible, depending on the size of the glass.

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KOO5S4vxi0o

Comment: @geometrikal Now I get it! Thank you for clarifying that for me.

Comment: My battery goes to 11.

Answer (score 4):

Well if you say 100% is the capacity of the battery specified by the manufacturer, then yes nearly all batteries are charged beyond 100%, as the manufacturer will indicate the minimum capacity, so they are not made liable for any failures concerning too little capacity.

But that's in the range of maybe a few percent and not a massive 375% or something like that.

The reaction to overcharging the battery is very dependent on the chemistry involved. Some will tend to explode (lithium ion and lithium polymer), others will just waste the additional charging current to heat.

The point made by PlasmaHH in the comment is actually a quite good one. If a battery could hold significantly more charge as advertised, the manufacturer would be quite dumb. Now you could argue, that a lot of ICs will also run at much higher speeds than advertised. But on closer inspection, not all ICs are able to, and that's why manufacturers turn the speed down to a level where every chip runs - it increases the yield and thus you can make more money. Batteries seem to behave more predictable for manufacturing.

Maybe a capacitor can handle more voltage and so store more energy than advertised. As the energy stored on a capacitor increases with the square of the voltage, you would need to double the voltage to store four times the energy.

That doesn't sound too bad actually - you might find some capacitors which are able to handle double the voltage specified as they are tested quite hard. But then the energy stored on capacitors is quite low compared to batteries. (There are massive capacitors, but you wouldn't want to carry one around)

Comment: In short, Overclocking is possible, but not recommended.

Comment: I really like your answer. I could understand 5... no no, 6... no, 7... Well, I could understand some words. I agree with everything in this (except the part about ICs, I don't understand anything about it... yet...). PlasmaHH's point was good, obviously. But obviously it was an obvious point. I wanted to know if it was possible to push a battery further than that. And explosions are awesome. But I want to keep away from them. But anyway. Thank you a lot for the answer.

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel you like an answer although you don't understand the majority of it? That is rather unusual. Maybe I can improve it somehow?

Comment: @Arsenal It was a failed attempt of a joke. The only thing I really dont get is about ICs, but that must be another question. That question, Google can answer me. Your answer is great, don't touch it. I was just joking.

Answer (score 1):

There are plenty of battery chemistry options which can be left on a charger without damage - but that doesn't lead to higher charge levels!

Fundamentally a battery works by adding and removing electrons from atoms in solution. This sets an absolute physical upper limit on how much energy it can hold, in the same way that you can't put more than 1L of fluid in a 1L bottle: once you've run out of atoms to change the charge state of, there is nowhere to put extra charge.

Comment: Actually, you can put a little bit more than 1l, depending of the physical properties of the container. I get your point, and I agree with you.

Answer (score 1):

NiMH batteries will take the excess charge current and liberate flammable hydrogen gas (which is vented to prevent the cell from exploding) plus heat, permanently reducing the capacity of the cell (damaging it). In extreme cases (like the example), thermal runaway takes place which doesn't just damage the battery, it destroys it on the spot in a geyser of electrolyte steam and liberated hydrogen. Lithium cells can turn into pyrotechnics, presumably incinerating the unfortunate Mr. Stark.

While it's possible that you might be able to get a small amount of extra capacity at the risk of damaging a battery in general, if 475% was possible they'd be using it.

Comment: "a geyser of electrolyte steam and liberated hydrogen" --> I always though that explosions were awesome. Not I think that they are amazingly awesome! To be honest, I don't care much how small the extra capacity is, as long as it is possible without reaching the part where I have fun watching from VERY far away. You made a good point about incinerating in the suit. I do really like your answer and the way you use your words. But how much do you think the battery would be able to withstand without turning into a geyser?

Comment: The battery manuals basically say any amount of overcharging damages the battery. I would guess the margin is less than 10%. Since it's damaged you've permanently reduced the capacity and you don't get back that extra energy.

Comment: As long as I don't have a pyrotechnic show, it doesn't matter. The important is to 'shove' the energy in there, somehow. If it loses energy, that is acceptable. You made a very good point that I didn't though about. Which is to try to use that extra energy we stored. I didn't though about that! But it is a good point and deserves recognition (and to be more explicitly explained on the answer, if possible). You almost blew my mind now!

Comment: If the energy does not come back out as electrical energy I don't see why you'd do it.

Comment: "You made a very good point that I didn't though about. Which is to try to use that extra energy we stored. I didn't though about that!" --> I think this explains it all. Right?

Answer (score 1):

As others have explained, what you call "100% charge" is definitely not fully charged. Battery people don't necessarily figure out what 100% charge really means because the battery usually explodes when you get there.

I'm most familiar with Li-ion batteries, so here's a quick "oh my god" situation:

The Li-ion batteries I work with have two flat electrodes rolled up with a separator in between so that the electrodes don't short together. If you hold a battery at high voltages and temperatures for a while, something similar to tin whiskers can form on the electrodes, causing a short and generating a lot of heat. The battery will probably catch on fire (and lithium fires are particularly nasty).

Note that charging batteries to higher voltages will also cause them to die in fewer cycles without a whole lot in return. Most of the capacity of a battery is in the lower (regular) voltage ranges, so adding an extra 100 mV of charge won't make your battery last as long on one charge as you think.

Comment: Batteries catching fire by themselves? Sounds..... fun? But honestly, I don't care if the batery dies in 2-3 cycles or that doesn't give a boost in usage time. All that matters is if you can put more charge in it than the one 'advertised', without the thing exploding. But I guess, from what I can understand, that the battery will simply short itself if I leave it long enough. I guess that, what you mean is 'charge it! It may handle more 100mV. If you leave it overnight, you might wakeup to fireworks!'. Am I wrong?

Comment: Well, depending on what you're doing with it, you might not wake up. But yes, if you pull the battery out of your phone and put a power supply across it, you can continue charging it until it isn't a battery, which will probably be a decent amount above the number written on the case.

Comment: PS: If you just leave it (open circuit), it'll discharge itself pretty quickly. I'm talking about putting in a trickle of current to keep the voltage constant.

Comment: "Well, depending on what you're doing with it, you might not wake up" --> The idea is to force it to receive and hold the charge above the limit. Which, as I expect, it might blow up and might not wake up. But you provided me with valuable information. Thank you a lot for the help.

Comment: hehe. What I meant is that a battery in your basement would be okay (just put out the fire and move on), but a battery strapped to your chest would be... uh, less pleasant.

Comment: I'm not Mehdi Sadaghdar (https://www.youtube.com/user/msadaghd/) to strap a battery on my chest. Unless it is the cellphone's battery. Then it might explode in me while I leave home. (Sometimes I change the factory parameters and pull 800mA out of the USB to charge the battery faster... for around 8-20 hours).